# I can't disable Parental Control on Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, parental-control

Since I transfer my daughter's data from Redmi Note 8T to Samsung A52 4G I noticed that in the Google Play Store the Parental Control has been activated and I cannot disabled it at all.
I already tried all the procedure found in the web (clear Play Store's data, delete Google account and restore it back, perform a factory reset) but no of them seem to work.
Does someone else get the same issue and know how I can solve?
Maybe some settings in the Google account that I forget to check.
(My daughter is 18 year old, so I can't really understand why the Parental Control has been activated)

Here is a short video showing the issue:
https://youtu.be/_5wB4xaAwXc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out there is a procedure to verify the age on Google account:
https://myaccount.google.com/age-verification

After verification, the Parental Control switched off automatically!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just had to restart the tablet after disabling the parental controls.